# Subversion server and client?

Tags: svn, version-control

Could anyone suggest a good subversion server and  a good subversion client which is compatible with linux,windows and MAC?

Comment: I like to have the client integrated in my IDE as a plugin, I don't know why a client should be platform independent. But to see changes, version notes or basic stuff WebSVN is nice.
to host the repository, see http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this one for client :

http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

It's the most widespread svn server [subversion](http://.apache.org/packages.html). It's the most widespread [svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) client for win[tortoise]. For linux you may use any from your linux repository.

Answer (score 0):

To setup a svn server you use apache which works on linux, windows and macs.

The [svn client](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) is also available for most popular operating systems.

If you are worried that a client for one OS will not be able to work with a server on a different OS don't. The SVN system is OS independent so you can use a mac client to connect to a windows SVN server.